# Create a table using the header and descriptions columns from a list that has multiple values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how can I use index and match to fill out a table based on  header  and  items?
I want to make a table  that  get the quantity of  items per  site, from my table that has  info  all mixed.

Is  INDEX and  MATCH the best  way ?

the table I want to  make:

```
ITEMS | SITE1 | SITE2 | SITE3| .... | SITE n |
----------------------------------------------
ITEM1 |   3   |   1   |      |      |        |
----------------------------------------------
ITEM2 |       |   3   |      |      |        |
----------------------------------------------
ITEM3 |   2   |       |      |      |        |
----------------------------------------------
```

My data table:

```
SITE  |  ITEM  | price | quantity  |
------------------------------------
site1 | item1  | XX    |     3     |
------------------------------------
Site1 | item3  | XX    |     2     |
------------------------------------
site2 | item1  | XX    |     1     |
------------------------------------
site2 | item2  | XX    |    3      |
```

Comment: Your best bet will be pivot table.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since the value sought is numeric, and there are multiple conditions, an array formula is the simplest solution.
Per image below: Assuming the data locations were as showing the image, the following would be the formula as it appears in cell B2:

```
{=SUM(IF($A$8:$A$13=B$1,IF($B$8:$B$13=$A2,$D$8:$D$13)))}
```

The formula gets the numeric value (via SUM) from column D in the table where site (column A) matches the corresponding value in row 1, and item (column B) matches the corresponding value in column A of the 'value sought' table.
Sample, as implemented
[image]

Notes:
o You don't enter the {}. Instead, use Ctrl, Shift and Enter to enter an Array formula
o The formula will work just as well with the data table in a separate sheet
o Array formulas generally return faster that lookup functions

Comment: Thank you so much  this  did  work  !  just  had some  issues  dragging the  formula a cross  and  down ! but it worked at the end

Comment: Glad to help. And yeah, that's one thing about array formulas (the fact you can't copy and paste a cell(s) inclusive of the cell(s) you're copying). Considered mentioning it but thought you'd figured out how... and you obviously did! :)